# How can I use a different SSH key to clone a second GitHub repository in CircleCI (either as the main clone or as a submodule)?

Tags: git, ssh, circleci

I have a GitHub project building in CircleCI which needs to clone another repository, also in GitHub. The second repo has a different SSH key added as a [Deploy Key](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/managing-deploy-keys/).

I tried [adding the key without a domain](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/multiple-ssh-keys-for-same-domain/14272) and specifying it with `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_<somehash>"`, but even then I get `Permission denied (publickey)`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be that CircleCI uses [`ssh-agent`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssh-agent), at least for the `github.com` host. The agent might treat this host a bit differently since it's the source of the main repo being built and there may be some integration logic to authenticate with that specific host. This might be true of other CI tools as well.

I could make it work [by specifying the `IdentitiesOnly` SSH option](https://superuser.com/questions/772660/howto-force-ssh-to-use-a-specific-private-key), which appears to sidestep the agent and forces the passed key to be the only tried key, rather than being treated as an *extra* as when this option is not present. In my tests, this worked for both `git clone` and `git submodule update`:

```sh
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_<somehash>" git clone
```

Or:

```sh
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_<somehash>" git submodule update
```

Answer (score 0):

I explicitly authorize then checkout each submodule using a CircleCI Command:

```
commands:
  checkout_submodule:
    description: |
        Given the fingerprint of the ssh key, will grant access and checkout submodule given. 
        This is required since only a single ssh key may be accessed.
    parameters:
      fingerprint: 
        type: string
        description: "The fingerprint for the ssh key "
        # provide access to submodule repos
        # https://circleci.com/docs/github-integration/
      submodule: 
        type: string
        description: "The name of the submodule (src path not included)"
    steps:
      - add_ssh_keys:
          fingerprints:
            - << parameters.fingerprint >>
      - run: 
          name: Checkout Git Submodule << parameters.submodule >>
          # git repos provide tag information for version matching
          command: git submodule update --init src/<< parameters.submodule >>
      - run:
          name: Reset ssh key 
          # multiple keys are not supported simultaneously. Each submodule must be granted individually
          command: rm ~/.ssh/config
```

which then I call for each submodule ...

```
- checkout_submodule:
    submodule: submodule_1
    fingerprint: 75:b2:56:00:54:03:59:94:53:13:56:0b:bb:50:e5:55
- checkout_submodule:
    submodule: submodule_2
    fingerprint: 8a:43:7a:45:91:85:15:63:2b:3e:85:a3:d7:b0:d9:95
```